# General administrator/deploy user permissions on centos

Tags: unix, permissions, centos, user-accounts, administrator

I'd like a user who is capable of managing the files of other users, but still must run sudo to access those files and functions outside of a /home/directory. Is such a user/group already defined in the unix/centos infrastructures? If not, what's a good way to acheive this?

Comment: Right now I'm looking at setting `chmod -R g+rwx admin` to all standard home directories and running `usermod -g admin deploy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELinux will allow you to do this. Create a role that has access to all home files and then assign this role to a user of your choice.

**EDIT:**

[IBM developerWorks: "Role-based access control in SELinux"](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-rbac-selinux/)

[RHEL 5 Deployment Guide: "Chapter 4. Security and SELinux"](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/selg-overview.html)

[SELinux Mandatory Access Control: "SELinux Lockdown Part Six: Customized SELinux Roles"](http://selinux-mac.blogspot.ca/2009/06/selinux-lockdown-part-six-customized.html)

Comment: It sure seems like you could expand on this answer a lot more.  At least provide links to some relevant documentation or some page/blog with a somewhat useful example.

Comment: @Zoredache: Done.